# Как реализовать Android Service, который не убивает система и который работает постоянно?

Tags: android, android-service

Есть задача: Реализовать подобие месенджера. С этим проблем нет. 
Проблема в уведомлении пользователя о новом сообщении.
Используя Service пытался сделать получение данных о новом сообщении и вывод уведомления. Все работает, но система убивает сервис, через некоторое время. Причем при закрытии приложения сразу. Хотя тот же Телеграм прекрасно работает закрытым и шлёт уведомления.

startForeground - не годится. Нужно, чтоб не было уведомления о запущенном сервисе. В Телеграмм ведь нет.

Подскажите, в какую сторону копать?

Comment: а чем вам пуши не угодили?

Comment: Во всех приложениях пуши реализуются с помощью Firebase